# Projection between subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Suppose I have two $k$ dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^d$, which I call $A$ and $B$. Let $\text{proj}_S (x)$ denote the projection of an $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ onto subspace $S$. Now is given that for all $a \in A$ if I project $a$ onto $B$, then the norm is preserved upto a multiplicative factor. I.e, $||\text{proj}_B(a)|| \geq (1 - c_0) ||a||$, $\forall a \in A$ and some specified constant $c_0 < 1$.

Does knowing this allow me to claim anything about norm preservation if I project from $B$ to $A$ instead, even if with a different constant than $c_0$? i.e, for the value of  $||\text{proj}_A(b)||$ as against $||b||$ for all $b \in B$? It's fairly straightforward to see that for $k=1$, that $||\text{proj}_A(b)|| \geq (1 - c_0) ||b||$ would also hold true. But I don't see how to prove anything similar for arbitrary $k$, or even if it would be necessarily true.